# Error: "cause: invalid distance too far back", when creating new project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When I run my app it is working and running perfectly but a small windows pops up which says:

```
Failed to complete Gradle execution.
Cause: Invalid distance too far back
```

No idea what happens to my Android Studio

Its highly appreciated for your help and answers!

Comment: Any solution you found for this?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone running into the same problem in future--

The problem is not with android studio, restart your computer. Launch Android Studio, it should resolve itself.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates a zip file corruption.

When using gradle wrapper `gradlew`, this could happen if gradle distribution has been corrupted during download.
Try to delete the corresponding file in `$HOME/.gradle/wrapper/dists/`

Answer (score -1):

Try gradle --stop in order to stop the daemons